# UIDatePicker locale day

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I writing an app in Xamarin.iOS but an answer in native will suffice. I want to localize my date picker so that it shows the picker in French. So far I did this:

```
Locale = new NSLocale("fr-CA");
```

It shows the month in French, but not the days of the week. Here is an image of the result:

[image]

How can I change the days of the week (SUN, MON, etc) to French?

Comment: Are you using the latest Xamarin.iOS version? I think your code is enough to change the days of the week (SUN, MON, etc) to French. Update your version to try again or have a try with other language to see if it work.

Comment: This calendar popup only appears when I test the app on the simulator. But not on a real device. On the real device I only get the spinner at the bottom of the screen which is localized correctly. I think this area is glitchy in the simulator.

Comment: Is your real device with iOS 14? [uidatepickerstyleinline](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickerstyle/uidatepickerstyleinline?language=objc) is only available in iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

In the bellow code language of the days of week will be changed according to the user preferences:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.locale = .autoupdatingCurrent
```